When is it okay to check and update state within a GET request
I have the following scenario:
We have a grid that allows the creation of reports. Report creation is asynchronous and happens in the background on worker nodes.
When a report is in the process of being generated, it is in a pending state and no other reports of the same type can be generated until the last report has either completed or failed.
I'd like to address the scenario where the creation of a report has neither failed or completed and is just stuck in the pending state. So essentially, i'd like to timeout reports that were queued before one hour ago and set their state to failed so that the user can generate another report.
The problem is the state is loaded when you hit the listing API endpoint. E.G. /api/v1/reports/.
Is it valid in this scenario to do a pre-check within the GET request logic to check if there are expired pending report jobs, and if so fail them before returning the listing data?
Pseudo code example:
#[Get('/api/v1/reports')]
public function getReports() {
    if (hasExpiredPendingReports()) {
         failExpiredPendingReports()
    }
    return getReports();
}

Is this a valid use case for a state changing operation with a GET request, or should i avoid this at all costs.
Ideally i need to update expired pending reports before the listing endpoint has loaded, so the only alternatives i can think of are:

A new API endpoint that is called and checks and updates the state which is invoked before the listing endpoint.
A scheduled job that runs every hour that updates pending jobs.

Would appreciate some feedback on this.

Could the clients of this endpoint tell if you did this, vs having a periodic job fail the reports instead?

Aside: checking to see if there is anything to do doesn't need to be a separate step. failExpiredPendingReports() doing nothing when there are no expired reports is fine.

Good point on third party clients. I've been thinking of purely internal use cases without thinking about third party consumers. That rules that option out.
Also valid point around the separate step, i just wanted to express the idea quickly, that isn't the actual code :)

@dmc On one hand, if you are only using this internally, you are pretty much free to do whatever you want.  I would caution against not following the standard semantics because it will violate the expectation of other developers and standards-based tooling.

One example could be when you need to record user activies. When the client GETs a resource on behalf of a user, the server could save a new user activity indicating that the user in question did consult the resource at a given time.

typo: set their state to pending -> set their state to failed

The section on 'safe' methods in RFC 7231 talks about this kind of thing:

This definition of safe methods does not prevent an implementation
from including behavior that is potentially harmful, that is not
entirely read-only, or that causes side effects while invoking a safe
method.  What is important, however, is that the client did not
request that additional behavior and cannot be held accountable for
it.

Emphasis is mine.  Think about it this way: if the client attempts to call a GET method but fails to receive or handle the response, it should be OK for it to call again, immediately.
I don't see anything about this that would be problematic in that sense because on repeated calls, you aren't going re-fail the jobs again, but we don't have the full context of the application/system so you really need to figure out if that's OK.

Thank you for your post. I don't believe repeated calls within our application would have any negative impact as in this scenario it is perfectly valid to invoke the endpoint over and over. So it sounds like this could be a valid option after all. I think i was concerned about violating general principles, but as you pointed out via the RFC, it appears to be acceptable under some circumstances.

@dmc Thanks for the checkmark.  For future reference, it's customary to wait a bit longer before accepting an answer, though. I don't think your situation here is very unusual. Making sure the state is up to date before returning a result is fairly typical, I think.  The main thing to consider is the performance implications.

Apologies, will remember that for next time. Thanks for your help.

@dmc No need for apologies. It's just that you might discourage other people from answering.  Sometimes the first answer might be OK but not the best one you'll get.

It's not a great solution to your problem.
In essence you are relying on the regular calling of an endpoint to run a scheduled task. If your endpoint doesn't get called, the task won't run. If the extra state setting logic breaks, the call will break.
It would be better to fix the problem in the existing report creation process, rather than tack on this work around.
